# What test to use for threshold

Tags: regression, estimation, threshold

I've got a problem where, with my basic knowlegde of statistical tests, I'm not sure how to solve it.

I have a dataset with data on the execution of a process. This includes:

- Time the process lasted
- The 'method' that was used (method A vs method B)
- The amount of subtasks type A the process had to perform (is differend by each process)
- The amount of subtasks type B the process had to perform (is differend by each process)

I'd like to find the threshold where 'method A' is faster than 'method B', so my IV's would be method, subtasks A, subtasks B and my DV would be time. Which statistical test should I use if I wanted to find a threshold?

Sample data: https://pastebin.com/w01HFGPE

Comment: Can you edit your question with some sample data? What do you mean by "threshold"? Are you trying to identify which method of A is faster than B?

Comment: It sounds like you're expecting one method to be faster for some ratio of subtasks A:B, and want to find the cutoff - is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. The version of the application is not really of importance, because this is going to be leveled over time. But subtasks A are light-weight, subtasks B are heavy-weight and I'd like to know when to use 'method A' over 'method B' to get the best performance time. I'll include some sample data soon.